The form data doesn't insert in access database in .NET application
I have an application written to run on .NET, and I have a problem: the Personnel data that I enter in a form and click the submit button isn't getting inserted into the MS Access database.
The model validation works, but when I click the submit button, the page reloads, but the data still is in the inputs, and not inserted into the database.
The connection string is correct because on another page I got the Personnel list from the database (the "Kadr" word in here is the
same personnel). Please help me and sorry if the English was bad (I have no errors).
These are my controller action methods:
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddKadr()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddKadr(Kadr kadr)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _dbService.AddKadr(kadr);
        return RedirectToAction("AddKadr");
    }

    return View(kadr);
}

This is my AddKadr method:
public async Task AddKadr(Kadr kadr)
{
    var result = new List<Kadr>();

    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        string query = "INSERT INTO Kadr (KadrName, KadrFamily, FatherName, CodeMelli, Birthday, Ostan, Shahrestan, City, Address, Marriage, Children, Son, Daughter, ShomareHesab, MobilePhone, HomePhone, Height, Weight, BloodType, Section, FieldofStudy, KadrGpa, OrganizationalHouse, Daraje, Raste, EstekhdamDate, PersonelNumber, Yegan, Ghesmat, Bakhsh) " +
                       "VALUES (@KadrName, @KadrFamily, @FatherName, @CodeMelli, @Birthday, @Ostan, @Shahrestan, @City, @Address, @Marriage, @Children, @Son, @Daughter, @ShomareHesab, @MobilePhone, @HomePhone, @Height, @Weight, @BloodType, @Section, @FieldofStudy, @KadrGpa, @OrganizationalHouse, @Daraje, @Raste, @EstekhdamDate, @PersonelNumber, @Yegan, @Ghesmat, @Bakhsh)";

        using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KadrName", kadr.KadrName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KadrFamily", kadr.KadrFamily);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", kadr.FatherName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeMelli", kadr.CodeMelli);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", kadr.Birthday);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ostan", kadr.Ostan);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shahrestan", kadr.Shahrestan);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", kadr.City);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", kadr.Address);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marriage", kadr.Marriage);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Children", kadr.Children);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Son", kadr.Son);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Daughter", kadr.Daughter);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShomareHesab", kadr.ShomareHesab);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhone", kadr.MobilePhone);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhone", kadr.HomePhone);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", kadr.Height);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", kadr.Weight);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodType", kadr.BloodType);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", kadr.Section);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldofStudy", kadr.FieldofStudy);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KadrGpa", kadr.KadrGpa);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationalHouse", kadr.OrganizationalHouse);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Daraje", kadr.Daraje);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raste", kadr.Raste);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstekhdamDate", kadr.EstekhdamDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonelNumber", kadr.PersonelNumber);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yegan", kadr.Yegan);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ghesmat", kadr.Ghesmat);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bakhsh", kadr.Bakhsh);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}

This is my view where the form is
@using Edari.Models
@model Kadr

<div class="shadow border-radius m-5 bg-light ">
    <div class="bd-example mt-5">
        <div class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <button class="nav-link active text-secondary" id="nav-kadr-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                data-bs-target="#nav-kadr" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-kadr"
                aria-selected="true">کادر</button>
            <div class="tab-content mainpage" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="nav-kadr" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-kadr-tab">
                    <form asp-action="AddKadr" asp-controller="Home" method="post" class="mx-5">
                        <div class="row input-group my-5 mb-5 mt-5">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.KadrName" class="form-control shadow-none rounded-3"
                                    placeholder="نام">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.KadrFamily"
                                    class="form-control shadow-none rounded-3" placeholder="نشان">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.FatherName"
                                    class="form-control shadow-none rounded-3" placeholder="نام پدر">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.CodeMelli" class="form-control shadow-none rounded-3"
                                    placeholder="کد ملی">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input placeholder="تاریخ تولد" asp-for="@Model.Birthday"
                                    class="form-control shadow-none rounded-3" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
                                    onblur="(this.type='text')">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row input-group my-5">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Ostan" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                    placeholder="استان">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Shahrestan"
                                    class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="شهرستان">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.City" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                    placeholder="شهر">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Address" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                    placeholder="آدرس">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row input-group my-5">
                            <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-around form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="marriage" asp-for="@Model.Marriage"
                                    class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-check-input">
                                <label for="marriage" class="form-check-label">وضیعت تاهل</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Children" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                    placeholder="فرزند">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Son" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                    placeholder="پسر">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Daughter" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                    placeholder="دختر">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.ShomareHesab"
                                    class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="شماره حساب">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row input-group my-5">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MobilePhone"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="شماره تلفن همراه">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.HomePhone"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="شماره تلفن ثابت">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row input-group my-5">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Height"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="قد">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Weight"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="وزن">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.BloodType"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="گروه خونی">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Section"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="مقطع">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.FieldofStudy"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="رشته تحصیلی">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.KadrGpa"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="معدل">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row input-group my-5">
                                <div class="col-md-2 form-check d-flex justify-content-around">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="OrganizationalHouse" asp-for="@Model.OrganizationalHouse"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-check-input" placeholder="خانه سازمانی">
                                    <label for="OrganizationalHouse" class="form-check-label">خانه سازمانی</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Daraje"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="درجه">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Raste" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                        placeholder="رسته">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input placeholder="تاریخ استخدام" type="text" asp-for="@Model.EstekhdamDate"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
                                        onblur="(this.type='text')">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.PersonelNumber"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="شماره پرسنلی">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row input-group my-5">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Yegan" class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control"
                                        placeholder="یگان">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Ghesmat"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="قسمت">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Bakhsh"
                                        class="shadow-none rounded-3 form-control" placeholder="بخش">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-end">
                                <input type="submit" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-success mb-5">
                            </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="mt-3 p-4">
                        <span asp-validation-for="KadrName"
                            class="m-2 mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="KadrFamily"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="FatherName"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="CodeMelli"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Birthday"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Ostan"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Shahrestan"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="City"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Address"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Children"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Son"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Daughter"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="OrganizationalHouse"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Marriage"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="ShomareHesab"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="MobilePhone"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="HomePhone"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Height"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Weight"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="BloodType"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Section"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="FieldofStudy"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="KadrGpa"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Daraje"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Raste"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="EstekhdamDate"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="PersonelNumber"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Yegan"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Ghesmat"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Bakhsh"
                            class="mb-2 bg-danger-subtle text-danger-emphasis rounded-3"></span><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



And this is the Kadr model class:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Edari.Models;

public class Kadr
{
    [Required]
    public int? KadrId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? KadrName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام خانوادگی الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? KadrFamily { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام پدر الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? FatherName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "کد ملی الزامی می باشد")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "کد ملی باید 10 رقم باشد")]
    public string? CodeMelli { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "تاریخ تولد الزامی می باشد")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "استان الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Ostan { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "شهرستان الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Shahrestan { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "شهر الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "آدرس الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وضیعت تاهل الزامی می باشد")]
    public bool Marriage { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "تعداد فرزند الزامی می باشد")]
    public int? Children { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن تعداد فرزند پسر الزامی می باشد")]
    public int? Son { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن تعداد فرزند دختر الزامی می باشد")]
    public int? Daughter { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "شماره حساب الزامی می باشد")]
     [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "شماره حساب باید 10 رقم باشد")]
    public string? ShomareHesab { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "شماره موبایل الزامی می باشد")]
     [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "شماره موبایل باید 11 رقم باشد")]
    public string? MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " شماره تلفن خانه الزامی می باشد")]
     [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "شماره تلفن خانه باید 8 رقم باشد")]
    public string? HomePhone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "قد الزامی می باشد")]
    public int? Height { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وزن الزامی می باشد")]
    public int? Weight { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "گروه خونی الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? BloodType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "مقطع الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Section { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "رشته تحصیلی الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? FieldofStudy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "معدل الزامی می باشد")]
    public decimal? KadrGpa { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "خانه سازمانی الزامی می باشد")]
    public bool OrganizationalHouse { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "درجه الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Daraje { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "رسته الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Raste { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "تاریخ استخدام الزامی می باشد")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? EstekhdamDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "شماره پرسنلی الزامی می باشد")]
     [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "شماره پرسنلی باید 11 رقم باشد")]
    public string? PersonelNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام یگان الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Yegan { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام قسمت الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Ghesmat { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام بخش الزامی می باشد")]
    public string? Bakhsh { get; set; }
}


Change and debug your AddKadr method like below. Since your connection you are confirmed as correct try breaking AddKadr method and wrapping it out by a try-catch block if there are any errors. Also, check to add an extra if condition to check whether the value is inserted or not via a meaningful message.
Refer to the code below for reference.
public async Task AddKadr(Kadr kadr)
{
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            string query = "INSERT INTO Kadr (KadrName, KadrFamily, FatherName, CodeMelli, Birthday, Ostan, Shahrestan, City, Address, Marriage, Children, Son, Daughter, ShomareHesab, MobilePhone, HomePhone, Height, Weight, BloodType, Section, FieldofStudy, KadrGpa, OrganizationalHouse, Daraje, Raste, EstekhdamDate, PersonelNumber, Yegan, Ghesmat, Bakhsh) " +
                           "VALUES (@KadrName, @KadrFamily, @FatherName, @CodeMelli, @Birthday, @Ostan, @Shahrestan, @City, @Address, @Marriage, @Children, @Son, @Daughter, @ShomareHesab, @MobilePhone, @HomePhone, @Height, @Weight, @BloodType, @Section, @FieldofStudy, @KadrGpa, @OrganizationalHouse, @Daraje, @Raste, @EstekhdamDate, @PersonelNumber, @Yegan, @Ghesmat, @Bakhsh)";

            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KadrName", kadr.KadrName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KadrFamily", kadr.KadrFamily);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", kadr.FatherName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeMelli", kadr.CodeMelli);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", kadr.Birthday);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ostan", kadr.Ostan);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shahrestan", kadr.Shahrestan);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", kadr.City);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", kadr.Address);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marriage", kadr.Marriage);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Children", kadr.Children);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Son", kadr.Son);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Daughter", kadr.Daughter);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShomareHesab", kadr.ShomareHesab);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhone", kadr.MobilePhone);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhone", kadr.HomePhone);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", kadr.Height);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", kadr.Weight);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodType", kadr.BloodType);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", kadr.Section);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldofStudy", kadr.FieldofStudy);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KadrGpa", kadr.KadrGpa);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationalHouse", kadr.OrganizationalHouse);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Daraje", kadr.Daraje);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raste", kadr.Raste);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstekhdamDate", kadr.EstekhdamDate);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonelNumber", kadr.PersonelNumber);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yegan", kadr.Yegan);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ghesmat", kadr.Ghesmat);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bakhsh", kadr.Bakhsh);

                int rowsAffected = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); // check if it goes to access sheet via rows effected

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Data inserted successfully."); // Insert successful
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Data insertion failed."); // Insert failed
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data: " + ex.Message); // Check if any exceptions
        }
    }
}

